# Why is there continuity between the leads of my DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, dc

I have a power supply that outputs constant 5v DC power. It's not adjustable or anything fancy. Using a multimeter, I found that there is continuity between the 2 output leads. Is this a bad thing? If not, then why does it happen?

Comment: It would depend on the design of the power supply (and if it's on or not at the time), and how the meter measures it, but in general it needs to both send current and receive the same amount of it at the other end, and when it does both at the same time and with the same quantity, it looks continuous (at least from one direction)

Comment: @user2813274 Your 'explanation' makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: It is only a bad thing if it causes the PSU to release magic blue smoke, otherwise its a design feature.

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams So why does no one use them as diodes ? Because it's non-sense what you say. What happens is that a reverse biased electrolytic capacitor gets hot, starts leaking DC current, might blow up, be damaged and become a short. But any electrolytic capacitor can handle a reverse small voltage for a short time without becoming a short.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Chemistry only explains different behaviour when reverse-polarised. Not creating a short. The short is caused by damage, this damage does not occur instantly. Just grab a lab-supply, an elco and a multimeter and reverse-polarize the capacitor. Then enlighten yourself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you measure this continuity ? In the diode/beep test of your multimeter ?
Now switch off the supply (very important !) wait a couple of minutes for verything to discharge and now measure again but use the Ohms range.
Is it 0 ohms ? I expect that it is not !

On my Fluke multimeter the continuity test already beeps when I connect 100 ohms.
So a continuity beep does not mean that it actually is a 0 Ohms connection !

Also there will be a lot of decoupling caps on that supply. When they're discharged it looks like a low ohmic connection (to the multimeter) so it beeps.
After some time (could take minutes) the caps are charged and the beeping stops.
Try that with a 100 uF capacitor (or larger) if you that lying around.

So no, it is not bad, just expected behavior ! In fact, this is how I would check that a supply is OK when a device is off, if I would measure 0 Ohms I would check if it might be shorted !

Comment: This makes sense! I forgot about the capacitors. Yes, I was using the beep test on my multimeter.

Answer (score 0):

There nothing bad about it, maybe the two leads are shorted internally to provide more current. What is the current rating?